# Aptana Studio: jQuery code completion/assist for variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, aptana, code-completion, code-assist

I have problems using the code completion/assist for jQuery in the latest Aptana plug-in (3.4). It doesn't seem to be able to infer types:

```
(function($) {
    $('p .test').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).*DOES WORK*
        $this.*DOESN'T WORK*
    });
}(jQuery));
```

When trying to get code completion for a variable created out of $(this), I don't get any assist :( Do you have any advice how to get this solved?

Comment: `var $(this)` is a syntax error. Did you mean `var $this = $(this)` instead of `var $(this) = $this`?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I meant var $this = $(this). But that doesn't work neither.

Comment: isn't here something useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458071/code-completion-aptana-eclipse-plugin#9917433

Comment: Did you set the project natures in Aptana? YOu can set them with "right click" on the project -> "properties" -> "project natures". Here you can set "web" and/or "PHP", if you are using PHP-libraries. And do you have the jQuery-scriptfile in the project directory?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
(function($) {
    $('p .test').each(function() {
        var ele = $(this);
        $ele = $(this);
        $(this).*DOES WORK*
        ele.*DOES WORK*
        $ele.*DOES WORK*
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I don't know how this is an answer, but `var this` is _definitely_ a syntax error.

Comment: @JanDvorak I forgot... Thanks :)! // Edited

Comment: Edit noted. Now you're spilling globals (`$ele`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, but defining everything globally ain't an option ;-) In addition $ele and ele don't work neither. Maybe, you have a different configuration. I have Eclipse Classic 4.2 (Juno) and the latest aptana plug-in (3.4.0.201304151542-7E7G-7MEMVKUHgFcLgFbkKoz0t-7)