# Javascript Weird construction in simple object?

Tags: javascript

http://jsbin.com/ufihev/3/edit

Pretty simple code :

```
var t = new function () //line 1
    {
        this.a1 = function () {

            return function () {
                alert("1");
            };
        }();
        this.a2 = function () {
            alert("a2");
        };

    }; //line 16
t.a1();
```

But **jsBin red line bellow** tells me :

> Line 1: var t = new function () --- Weird construction. Delete 'new'.
>
> Line 16: }; --- Missing '()' invoking a constructor.

the code is working fine.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Working fine in my Firefox/Chrome. Which browser are you running trouble into?

Comment: @Munim jsBin red line bellow .....Ive edited. look at the link . thanks.

Comment: @Munim it's working with two warnings.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274695/new-function-with-lower-case-f-in-javascript

Comment: @Hristo How the hell did you find this ??? :) thanks I  will look at that.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Your code is correct. However jsbin uses jslint. And jslint says "this code is silly". Thus it flags a warning. I recommend you don't use `new function () { }` because there are better alternatives.

Comment: @Hristo Still I cant understand why my code is BAd..... I've read the link answer , and the solution was to create an inside instance in autoexecute the wrapper function... thats fine also.. but I want to know why my code is bad

Comment: @Royi... I found it by doing a simple Google search. Here's another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440193/constructing-object-with-new-function-vs-invoking-function-with-function... but I can't exactly tell you why its bad. I'm not saying it is bad or good, it just seems that `new function() {}` is not common practice. Plus, if jsBin uses jsLint and jsLint was written by Douglas Crockford and it tells you to not do that, then I would listen because Douglas Crockford is the JavaScript guru.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to write an "anonymous type" equivalent to:

```
var _anonymous_type = function () {
    ...
}

var t = new _anonymous_type();
```

You should:

```
var t = new (function () {
    ...
})();
```

See the difference from you code? :)

Comment: The second is just an inlining of the first ... why would that be considered wrong?

Comment: @Jeffrey Zhao I got the same warning with your new suggesting (no pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var t = function () //line 1
    {
        this.a1 = function () {

            return function () {
                alert("1");
            };
        }();
        this.a2 = function () {
            alert("a2");
        };

    }; //line 16

var x = new t();
x.a1();
```

Comment: I can do that ALSO.... But my Code is syntactical fine. I can't see any reason why it wont work....

Comment: Technically there is nothing wrong with `var t = new function()...`, but there isn't a good reason to do that. Hence the *weird* constructor.