# Using a Javascript namespace/singleton won't accept arguments passed to member method

Tags: javascript, function, namespaces, singleton, arguments

Code of horror:

```
var namespace = new function ()
{
    this.saySomething = new function( something )
    {
        console.log( something );
    };
}

namespace.saySomething( "whatever" );
```

This outputs "undefined" when I expected it to output "whatever". How come? And what would the fix be? My goal is nothing more than to have a namespace where I put some helper functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `new` before the functions. `new` is only used for instantiating objects, when a constructor is already defined.

Your code should look like:

```
var namespace = {
    saySomething: function(something) {
        console.log(something);
    }
}

namespace.saySomething("whatever");
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this method because somebody might use your namespace  and can override and do namespace.saySomething = function( someotherthing ) { console.log( someotherthing ); /* and some more stuff here.*/ }.

Answer (score 3):

[`new function` is generally wonky.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274695/new-function-with-lower-case-f-in-javascript) Rob W's answer is absolutely correct (+1'd), but I would personally go even further and [remove all the `new`ing](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/hEVPH/):

```
var namespace = 
{
    saySomething: function( something )
    {
        console.log( something );
    }
}

namespace.saySomething( "whatever" );
```

If you want to be able to create distinct instances, [do it the right way](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/KXgvL/):

```
function Namespace() {}
Namespace.prototype.saySomething = function (something)
{
    console.log(something);
}

// Usage:
var foo = new Namespace();
foo.saySomething("Hallllooooo!");
```

...though you did say "singleton," so I'm guessing this isn't relevant to your goal.

Comment: Thanx. Yeah you're right, the prototype object for me in this particular situation is a little bit overkill. And I never intended to create a full blown singleton pattern either. So that's why I mixed together the words in the topic like so: "namespace/singleton". Appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `new` before `function(something){...}`. Currently, `saySomething` is an instance of the anonymous constructor.

Comment: Oh but of course, can't believe I missed that. Been awake for too long. Thank you so much for a superfast answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like the following because you also want to make sure that namespace doesn't get overridden by some other code.

```
var namespace = (function() {
      return {
          saySomething: function(something) {
               console.log(something);
          }
      };
})();

namespace.saySomething("whatever");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, sample http://jsfiddle.net/Jssxy/

```
var namespace = {
    saySomething : function(something) {
        console.log(something);
    }
}

namespace.saySomething( "whatever" );​
```