# What is the difference between function () {} and new function () {}

Tags: javascript, oop, object

What is the difference between

```
RGBCatcher = new function(){}
```

and

```
var Basket = function(){}
```

One has `new function()` whilst the other simply has `function()`. Also one is using `var`.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274695/new-function-with-lower-case-f-in-javascript

Comment: Changed title to better reflect the question. There is no jQuery here.

Comment: Neither of them are jQuery objects. This is just good ol' javascript.

Answer (score 2):

They're not jQuery objects. It's basic JavaScript syntax.

The difference between including a `var` or not is that omitting a `var` leaves the variable (`RGBCatcher`) to be declared implicitly in the global scope, which is bad practise; you should always use a `var` statement.

`function` by itself declares a function (in this case it's a function expression), so you can call `Basket()` to execute the function pointing to the `Basket` variable.

`new function` calls `new` on the anonymous function created by the `function` construct; It's the same as the following (except of course, you're not creating a function called `Constructor`);

```
function Constructor() {

}

var RGBCatcher = new Constructor();
```

Comment: I dont understand why you need a variable named Basket for a function. Whats the difference between saying function Baset() and var Basket = function(){}

Comment: @Ben_hawk: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this thread:

[`new function()` with lower case "f" in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274695/new-function-with-lower-case-f-in-javascript)

```
var a = new function(){

    var member = '1';
    alert(member);
}
```

// alerts 1

```
 var b=   function(){
    alert('2');
    return '2';
}();
```

// alerts 2

```
(function (){
    alert ('3');
    return '3';
})();
```

//alerts 3

```
alert (a);
```

// alerts [Object Object]

```
alert (b);
```

// alerts 2