# difference between function() {} and new function() {}

Tags: javascript

in this question, I don't want to ask "Function", i want to ask "function" puzzle

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = function() {
        alert('a');
    };

    var test1 = new function() {
        alert('b');
    };
</script>
```

why it will pop up the "b"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274695/new-function-with-lower-case-f-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Function (p1, p2, … , pn, body)

When the Function function is called with some arguments p1, p2, … , pn, body (where n might be 0, that is, there are no “p” arguments, and where body might also not be provided), the following steps are taken:

Create and return a new Function object as if the standard built-in constructor Function was used in a new expression with the same arguments.

check :[Is JavaScript's "new" keyword considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful)

Answer (score 0):

`new function` will execute the function, you can use an IIFE (Immediately- Invoked Function Expression) as well:

```
var test1 = (function() {
  alert('b');
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

`new` is used for the Factory pattern in Javascript.
It creates and returns an object by executing a constructor function. In your case it doesn't make sense to use `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions which are built to be used as constructors don't require parens, if you aren't passing any arguments:

```
var Person = function () { this.is_alive = true; },
    bob = new Person;

bob.is_alive;
```

...but any function can be called as a constructor, whether you're using the returned object or not...

```
new function () { console.log("Bob"); }
```

this won't save the function anywhere -- it will run it, in place, instantly.

Answer (score 0):

See [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) for a basic description of the new keyword.

Essentially, you are calling the constructor to a new object. Let me show you.

```
var Animal = function(name) {
    alert("Animal Created: " + name);
}

jaguar = new Animal("Cool");
```

The only difference from that and what you did was declare the function in the same line as defining the new object:

```
jaguar = new function(name) {
    alert("Animal Created: " + name);
}
```

That's why the "b" was printed out.