# Value of variable in nested function evaluate at definition time rather than at calltime

Tags: javascript, closures

Consider this code:

```
for( var i = 1; i <= 2; ++i )
{
 $( '#id' + i ).click(
   function()
   {
     alert( 'ID = ' + i );
   }
  )
}
```

The problem is that when id1 or id2 is clicked the alert always says ID = 3. Now I know why this happens (it is evaluated at call time), I am just curious if there is any way to prevent that? (1)

Many questions here and articles in general explain the concept of closure quite well, I have however been unable to find any technique to avoid it.

On a side note, I tried to use (note the extra keyword "new"):

```
new function() { alert( 'ID = ' + i ) }
```

however that calls the alert directly at the time it is defined and does nothing on click events. Any idea on this? (2)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to create a new scope where the value of `i` doesn't change. So to illustrate, you could create the function outside the loop, passing the current value:

```
function createClickAction(i){
    return function(){
        alert( 'ID = ' + i );
    }
}

for(var i = 1;i <= 2; ++i){
    $( '#id' + i ).click(
        createClickAction(i)
    );
}
```

But a shorter way to do the same thing is to pass the value into an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
for(var i = 1;i <= 2; ++i){
    (function(i){
        $( '#id' + i ).click(
            function(){
                alert( 'ID = ' + i );
            }
        );
    })(i);
}
```

Here is some discussion about the syntax [new function(){...}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274695/new-function-with-lower-case-f-in-javascript)
It has the same effect as an IIFE because you are instantiating an anonomous function, as a constructor. So it's like saying:

```
function Message(){
    alert('hi');
}
new Message();
```

...but without the naming.
And to pass arguments in:

```
new function(msg){
    alert(msg)   
}('hi');
```

So you were probably close to finding this solution:

```
for(var i = 1;i <= 2; ++i){
    new function(i){
        $( '#id' + i ).click(
            function(){
                alert( 'ID = ' + i );
            }
        );
    }(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Very well explained.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be like this.

HTML

```
<div id="id1">ID1</div>
<div id="id2">ID2</div>
<div id="id3">ID3</div>
```

Javascript

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i += 1) {
    (function (j) {
        $('#id' + j).click(

        function () {
            alert('ID = ' + j);
        });
    }(i));
}
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/jUMEd/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the working solution. I chose robC's answer because is much more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

how about -

```
for( var i = 1; i <= 2; ++i )
{
 $( '#id' + i ).click(
   function()
   {
     alert( 'ID = ' + this.id.substring('#id'.length) );
   }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This (most likely) works for my given example. I was, however, interested in the solution concept in general (e.g. see robC's answer).