# JavaScript - added function to onclick attribute of <a> runs without click

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have a function that creates a new `<a>` element and I want to add a onclick event to it, which is a function that increases the given value by 1.

In the function, I create these elements:

A number within spantags:

```
        var spantags = document.createElement("span");
        var anzahl = 1;
        spantags.innerHTML = anzahl;
```

And the mentioned `<a>` element:

```
        var plus = document.createElement("a");
        plus.innerHTML = "+";
        plus.onclick = more(spantags.innerHTML);
```

This, however, executed the function already in the function that creates this, so the number was increased to 2 on creation.

I read this answer on a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/249084/1972372

This example worked, the alert only came up when the + was clicked on, but it is an inner function there, not a declared one like my "more(element)".

**So my question is:** Is it possible to set the onclick attribute to a declared function on a newly created element, like in my example, but prevent it from running immediately?

(The other article had a jQuery answer too, but unfortunately I have no knowledge about jQuery and cannot use it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just wrap it in a "proxy" function:

```
plus.onclick = function() {
    more(spantags.innerHTML);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but first you have to understand that `plus.onclick = more(spantags.innerHTML);` will call `more` with the argument `spantags.innerHTML` and assign the result that is returned from that function call to `plus.onclick`.

You could wrap it in a proxy function as suggested previously, or you could take advantage of the `bind` method to bind the arguments to the function itself:

`plus.onclick = more.bind(null, spantags.innerHTML);`

Read up on Bind here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: This wouldn't actually have the same result.  You'd be binding the current value of spantags.innerHTML ("1" at the time of binding), and will never increment past 2

Comment: It actually works with this, so I'll give this an upvote too, but I am confused about what the first parameter is.   
I read that it is the this argument, but I still don't really get it.  

I accepted the first answer because it was easier to understand.

Comment: It's the "this" context.  In the callback itself, using "this" will reference whatever you pass in as the first argument (in this case "null").