# Change onclick action with a function containing parameters

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

In my sample HTML code i got some buttons with a default function to change the text and style on `onclick` event:

```
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Hit Me!</button><br>
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Hit Me!</button><br>
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Hit Me!</button><br>
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Hit Me!</button><br>
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Hit Me!</button><br>

<script>
function changeText(id) {
    id.innerHTML = "Ouch!";
    id.style.color="red";
    id.onclick= again(this);
}

function again(id) {
    id.innerHTML = "Again!";
    id.style.color=#FF0000;
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to change the `onclick` event at the end of the default function:

```
id.onclick= again(this);
```

But it doesn't work;

This is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/alexjolig/7jp8xdqa/)

I've tried solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249074/how-to-change-onclick-handler-dynamically) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303899/change-onclick-action-with-a-javascript-function)

this:

```
 id.onclick = function(this) { id.innerHTML = "Again!"; id.style.color=#FF0000; }
```

and this:

```
 id.setAttribute( "onclick", "javascript: again(this);" );
```

but none of them works.

*notice that I need `this` as the parameter to send into the function.*

*And I need a `javascript` solution not `JQuery`*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had some syntax errors, `id.style.color=#FF0000;`, the hex value should be a string. `id.style.color="#FF0000";`

And in this line:

```
id.onclick = again(this);
```

You're calling the `again` function & assigning the return value to `id.onclick`. If you want to assign a function just use `id.onclick = again`

Here's your code working, with some minor modifications.

```js
function changeText(element) {
    element.innerHTML = "Ouch!";
    element.style.color="red";
    element.onclick = again; //Assign "again" function.
}

function again() {
    //this is the clicked element.
    this.innerHTML = "Again!";
    this.style.color="#FF0000";
}
```

```css
 button {
  font-size:20px;
  color:#0C6C89;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Hit Me!</button><br>
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Hit Me!</button><br>
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Hit Me!</button><br>
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Hit Me!</button><br>
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Hit Me!</button><br>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. the minor changes were important ones which I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
id.onclick= function onclick(event){again(this);}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need lowcoupling you could do this:

```
function changeText(id) {
    id.innerHTML = "Ouch!";
    id.style.color= "red";
    // send the id
    id.onclick= again(id);
}

function again(id) {
    id.innerHTML = "Again!";
    id.style.color = "#FF0000";
}
```

Comment: You're calling again function, you're not assigning again to onclick, you're assigning its return value.